# Services Discovery of IoT device

Tags: semantic-web, semantics, iot

I am looking to discover services offered by one of my IoT device/Gateway.
The Gateway device is mDNS enabled, So I can discover device locally with mDNS discovery, at this point I can see my Gateway ip address and port its listenning on.

Now I want to query what all the services offered by the same device, how Can I do that. (Assuming gateway device has http REST Service )

Is there any Semantic query for IoT devices? or any other to ask for services offered by device?

Any direction or guidance, Thanks in advance

~Ashok

Comment: As far as I know, there is none so far. IBM has been active in linked-data IoT efforts: https://www.ibm.com/devops/method/content/architecture/iotArchitecture The basis for the linked data part is based on [OSLC](https://open-services.net/). If you are interested, shoot an email to the [public mailing list](https://open-services.net/mailman/listinfo) (probably, OSLC-AM is best).